# Gradle multi project - execute root task only once

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am working with the following project structure
Project

---Subproject1

---Subproject2

---Subproject3

|build.gradle

|settings.gradle

Subproject2 depends on Subproject 1

Subproject3 depends on Subproject 2

For all subprojects I need to have task "build", which will be custom for each project. But some initialization task (same for all subprojects) must be executed before "build". Thing is - this initialization task must be executed once and only once during build, no mater what I'm building - root project or any of subprojects.
For example, if I do build of Subproejct3, sequence must be following:
init
build Subproject1
build Subproject2
build Subproject3

I tried to define "doFirst" for "build" at root project build.gradle and put "init" code into it. But in this case "init" code executed before each "build".
I tried to define dependency on root for each "build" but faced same problem as previously.

Comment: Did you get an answer ? I too face the same issue.

Comment: Yes, exactly like Radim wrote below. Just add dependency from rootproject task in terms ':<rootProjectTaskName>' and it works

Answer (score 4):

This is quite simple with Gradle. Define your `init` task (probably in root project) and customize `build` tasks in your subprojects to depend on this init like

`build.dependsOn ':init'`

More details at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html

BTW: every tasks can be executed only once when a build is started so it seems that you have added your task action using doFirst() multiple times or added it to multiple tasks that were executed.